# Spring LockRegistryLeaderInitiator get leader role

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am currently working with an implementation based on:

> org.springframework.integration.support.leader.LockRegistryLeaderInitiator

supporting different leader candidate roles, so that the leader node for each role will only be allowed to execute schedulers. Overall, the cluster will have two leader nodes: one for scheduling1 and one for scheduling2 roles. Each role will be assigned to execute different schedulers. You can find below the xml configuration:

```
<bean id="scheduling1LeaderInitiator" class="org.springframework.integration.support.leader.LockRegistryLeaderInitiator">
    <constructor-arg name="locks" ref="jdbcLockRegistry"/>
    <constructor-arg name="candidate" ref="scheduling1LeaderCandidate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="scheduling1LeaderCandidate" class="org.springframework.integration.leader.DefaultCandidate">
    <constructor-arg name="id" value="#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="role" value="scheduling1"/>
</bean>


<bean id="scheduling2LeaderInitiator" class="org.springframework.integration.support.leader.LockRegistryLeaderInitiator">
    <constructor-arg name="locks" ref="jdbcLockRegistry"/>
    <constructor-arg name="candidate" ref="scheduling2LeaderCandidate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="scheduling2LeaderCandidate" class="org.springframework.integration.leader.DefaultCandidate">
    <constructor-arg name="id" value="#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="role" value="scheduling2"/>
</bean>
```

Although I can set in the LockRegistryLeaderInitiator constructor the Candidate, there is no way to get back the candidate’s role, or simply I am missing something. I would expect that Context will provide access to this information, since there are several leader instances for each role assigned. For example:

```
if (leaderInitiator.getContext().isLeader()) {
    String role = leaderInitiator.getContext().getRole();
}
```

which is currently missing from Spring implementation.

Spring integration version: 5.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a reasonable request; please open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

A bit ugly, perhaps, but as a work around you could parse it out of `context.toString()`...

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LockContext{role=" + LockRegistryLeaderInitiator.this.candidate.getRole() +
            ", id=" + LockRegistryLeaderInitiator.this.candidate.getId() +
            ", isLeader=" + isLeader() + "}";
}
```

You'd have to protect the parser code against getting back the `NULL_CONTEXT` lambda.

Comment: Thanks Gary. To overcome this I already used the "ugly" toString(). Jira ticket will be filled soon.